# Can we emplace small object on void*?

Tags: c++, pointers, optimization

Suppose there's API like below:

```
typedef void callback_t(void* data);

void addCallback(handle_t h, callback_t callback, void* data);
```

I'd like to wrap this API to a higher order C++ interface:

```
template<class F, bool emplace = IsEmplaceable<F>::value>
struct MakeCallback;

class Handle
{
    template<class F>
    void addCallback(F f)
    {
        ::addCallback(_h, MakeCallback<F>::f, MakeCallback<F>::create(f));
    }

    handle_t _h;
};
```

so that the user can pass any callable object (e.g. lambda function).

I'd like to apply small object optimization to avoid dynamic alloc (e.g. for empty lambdas), the trait `IsEmplaceable<F>` decides whether `F` can be emplaced in a `void*`.

For `F` that is not emplaceable, `MakeCallback` can be implemented like below:

```
template<class F>
struct MakeCallback<F, false>
{
    static void f(void* data)
    {
        auto f = static_cast<F*>(data);
        (*f)(status);
        delete f;
    }

    static void* create(F& f)
    {
        return new F(std::move(f));
    }
};
```

For `F` that is emplaceable, how could I properly implement the following?

```
template<class F>
struct MakeCallback<F, true>
{
    static void f(void* data)
    {
        // from void* to F
    }

    static void* create(F& f)
    {
        // form F to void*
    }
};
```

More basically, can a `void*` hold a non-address value if we don't use it as a pointer? will it be UB?

Comment: Only data that can be trivially copied is safe: otherwise the copies of the `void*` are problematic.  I don't think lambdas are technically ever trivial to copy?  Maybe?

Comment: @Yakk, FWIW, boost::has_trivial_copy returns `true` for an empty lambda, but that's not the point of this question, I just wonder whether `void*` can hold non-address data.

Comment: @Jamboree: I think technically it's undefined except for `char[]` and `unsigned char[]`, but I'm not sure.  It might be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's implementation-defined behavior according to the C++ standard (draft N3797).

§ 3.7.4.2/p4

> Indirection through an invalid pointer value and passing an invalid
>   pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior. **Any
>   other use of an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined
>   behavior**.

footnote 38:

> Some implementations might define that copying an invalid pointer
>   value causes a system-generated runtime fault

§ 3.7.4.3/p4

> An implementation may have relaxed pointer safety, in which case the
>   validity of a pointer value does not depend on whether it is a
>   safely-derived pointer value. Alternatively, an implementation may
>   have strict pointer safety, in which case a pointer value referring to
>   an object with dynamic storage duration that is not a safely-derived
>   pointer value is an invalid pointer value unless the referenced
>   complete object has previously been declared reachable (20.7.4) [...] **It is implementation
>   defined whether an implementation has relaxed or strict pointer safety**.

(emphasis mine)

So it is safe if the implementation has relaxed pointer safety, and we can use the `union` trick as shown in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26666941/2969631) from [@Smith_61](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3935776/smith-61) to avoid strict aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

A very big warning should be mentioned before even attempting the code shown in this answer. Doing this is most likely very very undefined and not portable behavior. I would highly suggest not doing this as it could very well break a long time into the future and you will have a very hard time finding out why.

That being said, it appears to work on at least my compiler. Results may vary for other compilers. I use a union to convert between a class instance and a void *, don't know of any other clean way to do this. This should work as long as `sizeof( Class ) <= sizeof( void * )`, but I make no guarantees on behavior with different compilers or even with the exact same compiler I used on my exact same setup.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Small {
public:
    int i;
};

void *castToVoid( Small& s ) {
    union {
        Small s;
        void *p;
    } un;
    un.s = s;
    return un.p;
}

Small castToSmall( void *p ) {
    union {
        Small s;
        void *p;
    } un;
    un.p = p;
    return un.s;
}

int main( ) {
    Small s;
    s.i = 100;

    void *p = castToVoid( s );

    s.i = 200;
    cout << p << endl; // Prints 0x64

    Small s2 = castToSmall( p );
    cout << s2.i << endl; // Prints 100
}
```

or this example for converting to/from a void *

```
void *castToVoid( Small& s ) {
    void **p = reinterpret_cast< void ** >( &s );
    return *p;
}

Small castToSmall( void *p ) {
    Small *s = reinterpret_cast< Small * >( &p );
    return *s;
}
```

Comment: That seems a trick to avoid strict-aliasing (failed to compile in VC10 though), but what I really worried about is whether `void *p = /*non-address*/` results in UB.

Comment: What is the error in VC10? Compiles fine on GCC 4.8.1. BTW the class Small can not contain a constructor, or it won't work.

Comment: Not in your example, but use lambda type in union fails to compile in VC10 which is before c++11 standard.

Comment: @Jamboree added another way to convert to/from a void *, and to better answer your question, most likely this is UB. I don't have to time right now to read the standard to confirm though.

Comment: Actually that's what I did, but I believe this violates strict-aliasing rule. Maybe I should give up this optimization for the sake of portability...

Comment: @Jamboree it definitely does violate strict aliasing, which means it is undefined behavior. So you shouldn't do it, but that doesn't mean C/C++ compilers won't let you.